# Can JTAG vulnerability lead to newer hardware support by coreboot? (bootguard bypass)

Tags: uefi, bios, thinkpad, vulnerability, coreboot

A of couple days ago I've stumbled upon this speech:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CQUNd3oKBM

The guy in the video speaks about Intel Mangement Engine, describes in details how it works and that he exploited it over JTAG. This exploit lets you run your own code on Intel ME.

All code on the ME is signed, the keys are in FUSEs (readonly memory), but ME loads manually the keys into register, so you can feed the register with your own keys. So we can trick BG. As I know from the forum page here ( https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/qubes-users/dlNu2Iv9MCU ) the main coreboot problem is the BG because there is even this video here ( [https://www.google.com/url?q=https://twitter.com/*zaolin*/status/1097966252625149952%3Flang%3Den&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjGlJar4PznAhXztHEKHcsnD_EQtwIwAXoECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0Ii-ufcV7uluw5LzRYECTY](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://twitter.com/_zaolin_/status/1097966252625149952%3Flang%3Den&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjGlJar4PznAhXztHEKHcsnD_EQtwIwAXoECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0Ii-ufcV7uluw5LzRYECTY) ) where the developer runs coreboot on a ThinkPad T480s!!! BUT the unlocked sample (that's impossible to get), so without BG.

I ask for your help professional coders, because I understand not everything of all what I've heard/read (I'm only learning).

- Does this mean that "soon" we will have coreboot support for newer hardware and how much time will this "soon" take?
  (Coreboot isn't dead but at the same time's not active)
- Is the T440p coreboot support out/almost out because of this vulnerability research?[ANSWERED]
- How the guy from the video (first link) got a T460 to work if there is no coreboot image out there to flash?

UPDATE1:
T440p is coreboot compatible because of Haswell BG that's incomplete and works only on BGA chips.
Coreboot is active in chromebooks support development.

Cheers Yugene:)

Comment: If you're looking for an audience of "professional coders", you probably want to move this question from U&L to Stack Overflow. As-is, I don't see it in-scope at U&L.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware question (Intel Management Engine) which executes long before Unix even comes into the question